# Stream Parse Wiki Xml dump

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, wikipedia, topic-modeling

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before but it has been I couldn't find it and please pardon my ignorance. I want to parse (stream parse) wikipedia xml dumps that are about 40 Gigs. I'm trying to use lxml iterparse aka stream parser to do this job for me but the code I wrote isn't working for me for some reason. Before I explain what I want to do let's consider this xml format

```
<root>
  <page>
    <title> A  </title>
    <text> ..........blah blah...... </text>
  </page>

  <page>
  <title> B </title>
  <text> This is a line of sample text in title B  </text>
  </page>

  <page>
  <title> C </title>
  <text> ............blah blah........ </text>
  </page>
</root>
```

In the above xml structure, which is very much what wiki dump has, what I want to do is read each and every thing inside "page" tag (which basically separates different articles in the dump) using a python stream parser such as lxml (without loading the entire xml tree into memory which is impossible) and do a regular expression stuff on it. Precisely what I want to do is, if in the current "page" element look for inside the text tag "Category:Living People", if such a matching regex is found, then write out the entire content inside "text" tag into a text file. But before the regex part, I'm having issues with the lxml parser itself. Sample code that I tried below. Thanks in advance :)

```
#LXML parser
from lxml import etree

def fast_iter(context, func):
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def process_element(elem):
    print elem.xpath( 'description/text( )' )

context = etree.iterparse( MYFILE, tag='item' )
fast_iter(context,process_element)
```

Feel free to completely alter the code and give your own version, I really wouldn't mind as long as I get my problem sorted!

Someone help please!

Comment: Can you narrow down the question please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. Can you help me parse the xml (take the example structure) and print out all the content inside <text> tag in a file?

Comment: I just need an example code that will work for this xml structure. I'm not a python expert, so bit of problem there as well. My apologies

Comment: So, how does your code fail? What *does* it do?

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.sax import ContentHandler, parseString
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

CONTENT = """
<root>
  <page>
    <title> A  </title>
    <text> ..........blah blah...... </text>
  </page>

  <page>
  <title> B </title>
  <text> This is a line of sample text in title B  </text>
  </page>

  <page>
  <title> C </title>
  <text> ............blah blah........ </text>
  </page>
</root>
"""

def fast_iter(context, func):
    for action, elem in context:
        func(elem)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def process_element(elem):
    print elem.xpath( './text/text( )' )

class WikiContentHandler(ContentHandler):

    def startDocument(self):
        self.character_buffer = None

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'text':
            self.character_buffer = StringIO()

    def endElement(self, name):
        if name == 'text':
            print self.character_buffer.getvalue()
            self.character_buffer.close()
            self.character_buffer = None

    def characters(self, content):
        if self.character_buffer != None:
            self.character_buffer.write(content)

def parse_wiki():
    parseString(CONTENT, WikiContentHandler())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_wiki()

    context = etree.iterparse( StringIO(CONTENT), tag='page' )
    fast_iter(context, process_element)
```

Above are two ways of parsing the XML, one using lxml, the other using the Python standard library.  Both of them print out all the information in the `<text>` tags.  Just look where the print statements are and do your additional processing.

Comment: This is not clear at all. Which one is which? You've declared content but you don't seem to be using it anywhere; in either examples.

Comment: CONTENT is used in parseString(), which uses the SAX parser included with python.  The other parser is etree.iterparse( StringIO(CONTENT), tag='page') which uses lxml.  You'll need to scroll the code down to see where CONTENT is used.